# WMI script failing with an error 0x80041017

Tags: vbscript, wmi

I have a very simple WMI test-script that I am running locally on a server to diagnose a problem I'm having getting WMI some data.

Essentially, *all* WMI queries I run on this machine (locally) fail with an error code `0x80041017`.

```
Option Explicit

Dim WmiQuery
WmiQuery = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor"

Dim objSWbemLocator
Set objSWbemLocator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator") 

Dim objWMIService
Set objWMIService = objSWbemLocator.ConnectServer("localhost", "root\cimv2")

Dim results
Set results = objWMIService.ExecQuery (WmiQuery)

Dim row
For Each row in results
Next
```

I'm not even trying to view any properties yet, but it fails on line 16, which is the `For Each row in results` line.

Here's the output of running it in a console:

```
c:\test>cscript test.vbs
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

c:\test\test.vbs(16, 1) (null): 0x80041017
```

Running that query through wbemtest gives the description "Invalid query", even though the same query runs on other servers. Is something not registered in WMI or something?

Comment: Nothing inherently wrong with your script. Check WMI with [`WBEMTest`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692770.aspx) and/or [`WMIDiag`](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2012/02/03/wmidiag-2-1-is-here.aspx).

Comment: Try [rebuilding the WMI repository](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2009/04/13/wmi-rebuilding-the-wmi-repository.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be to do with how you're getting your WMI object.

How about this:

```
Option Explicit

Dim wmi,col,itm

Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set col = wmi.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Processor")

For Each itm in col
  WScript.Echo itm.Name
Next
Set wmi = Nothing
Set col = Nothing
WScript.Quit
```

Seems to work for me... Don't think you need all the WBemLocator guff...